# How to search sunspot rails for empty associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

Before, we were able to successfully find 'roots' in a tree by checking for an empty previous_id:

```
Phrase.search do
  with :previous_id, nil
end.results
```

Now we successfully changed the model from 1:n (belongs_to) to n:n (has_and_belongs_to_many).

We upgraded the searchable segment from

```
integer :previous_id #, :references => Phrase
```

to

```
integer :previous_ids, :multiple => true, :stored=>true do
    previous.reload
    previous_ids #OK!
end
```

Everything works fine except that the following search for nodes with empty associations returns **all** nodes:

```
Phrase.search do
  with :previous_ids, nil
end.results
```

How to search sunspot rails for empty associations?

Comment: Does `with :previous_ids, []` work?

Comment: no, it doesn't, but as a workaround we introduced an integer previous_count field